# How can I make a perfect M6 screw?

Tags: modeling, add-on

Not with manual way, is there any addon or perfect way that can make a M6 screw? Must be able to fit a 6x12 sign in landscape that will have two holes at the center point 0.30”/7.62 mm from the top and bottom with M6 screws. Any suggestion or help how it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an add-on that's included but not enabled called *[Bolt Factory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/boltfactory.html#bolt-factory)* that has an M6 preset:

[image: Last Operator Adjust panel after adding a bolt showing the M6 setting]

The problem is that its scale is off, but if you scale the screw by 1 / 1000 you'll get the correct scale.

Comment: Thanks, what type of M6 it will would be, bit type and head?

Comment: You can choose.  Underneath the dropdown there are other dropdowns for those.

Answer (score 11):

You can try *[BoltFactory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/boltfactory.html#bolt-factory)* add-on. It's native, you just have to enable it at *Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons -> Add Mesh: BoltFactory*:

[image]

Once enabled, you can go to *Add* <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *-> Mesh -> Bolt*:

[image]

A window will pop on the left where you can customise the settings to create pretty much any kind of Bolt / Screw / Nut you want:

[image]