# How can fix the M6 screw in the hole

Tags: modeling, add-on

With reference of the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237421/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-m6-screw)

[image]

I tried to scale 1/1000. But the M6 screw does not fit in the 6mm hole.

[image]

Whats going wrong or how can i fix. So the screw and bolt fix in the hole with accurate measurement

[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KtAn.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Two things are not right :

1: In your Video it shows that you have Added a M3 bolt instead of a M6.
[image]

2: The diameter of the hole is way to big (9mm). Note that the diameter of the bolt in the image below is after applying the scale.
[image]

The "fix" is, when adding the bolt choose the correct size from the Operator Presets options :
[image]

......and correct the hole size in the model.

You can check dimensions in edit mode by enabling the Measurement option from the Overlays drop-down menu. Very important is to first **Apply Scale** in **Object** mode. ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open the **Apply** menu then choose the **Scale** option ).
[image]